# Help window automatically opening every time for opened window

Tags: unity

Whatever I'm working, every time a help pop-up is opening.
Like when I am working on terminal, terminal help is reopening every time.
If Mozilla is opened, Mozilla help is opening ...

I am new to Ubuntu, please help..

Comment: Today booting a live DVD I also had help randomly popping up once. I am wondering why this is too, just for curiosities sake.

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is opening when you press key **h** then your *Alt* key could be stuck. Try pressing on it to help proiper releasing.