# All apps automatically open up 'Help'

Tags: 20.04

From the past day or two whenever I open an application (LibreWriter, AisleRiot, Files, Document Viewer) the 'Help' for all these applications opens up. Once open, they do not remain closed when I close them - another one opens up. Sometimes it will stop after 10-12 times of closing it but sometimes it does not.

[Help window automatically opening every time for opened window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657847/help-window-automatically-opening-every-time-for-opened-window)

^This suggests an issue with the Alt key, although that doesn't seem to be the issue since (as suggested in the link) I do not need to press H key for the 'Help' window to be launched.

Comment: Welcome, problems with F1 key maybe?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Any idea how I can check/solve that issue?

Comment: Try this, in the command line run this command: `xev | grep --line-buffered F1`. If F1 is pressing by itself, you should see a message.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I ran the command. It constantly gave the message: state 0x10, keycode 67 (keysym 0xffbe, F1), same_screen YES

Comment: That' means your F1 key is pressing by itself.

Comment: I see. I'll look for ways to fix that. Thank you!